# Computing generalized eigen values for sparse matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, scipy, linear-algebra

I am using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh to solve the generalized eigen value problem for a very sparse matrix and running into memory problems. The matrix is a square matrix with 1 million rows/columns, but each row has only about 25 non-zero entries. Is there a way to solve the problem without reading the entire matrix into memory, i.e. working with only blocks of the matrix in memory at a time?

It's ok if the solution involves using a different library in python or in java.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you're already using ARPACK. You'll probably have to go to either the FORTRAN implementation of ARPACK, or use ARPACK++ to get the fine grained memory control you need...

Comment: have you tried the [Shift-invert mode ?](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html) . Also, do you really need all the eigenvalues (you could just compute the largest ) ?

Answer (score 3):

For ARPACK, you only need to code up a routine that computes certain matrix-vector products. This can be implemented in any way you like, for instance reading the matrix from the disk.

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

def my_matvec(x):
    y = compute matrix-vector product A x
    return y

A = LinearOperator(matvec=my_matvec, shape=(1000000, 1000000))
scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A)
```

Check the scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh documentation for what is needed in the generalized eigenvalue problem case.

The Scipy ARPACK interface exposes more or less the complete ARPACK interface, so I doubt you will gain much by switching to FORTRAN or some other way to access Arpack.